# Using Devise tokens to log in, is this built in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token

So, I'm trying to use tokens with Devise (version 1.0.3 with Rails 2.3.8) to let a user log in, but I'm not entirely sure where to begin.

http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise

The above tutorial helped me turn on the token functionality, and showed how to generate (or delete) tokens...but the whole POINT of tokens is to use them to authorize a user, correct?

When I look at a user in the console, I can say user.authentication_token, and get something back like: "Qm1ne93n_XkgmQTvxDmm", which is all well and good...but where do I go from there?

I tried hitting the sign_in root using the following command line command:

> curl -d "authentication_token=Qm1ne93n_XkgmQTvxDmm" localhost:3000/users/sign_in

And definitely didn't get a successful log in.

In the sessions controller, I see that they call:

> authenticate(resource_name)

Which I'm ASSUMING is somewhere in the module:

> include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers

which gets included, but I don't know where to look for that (it's definitely not in the source's controller folder). If I could look at how authenticate works, I could see if it even LOOKS at tokens...

DOES Devise let you actually log in with tokens, or does it just have a framework for generating them? If it does let you log in with them...HOW do you do this? Can you not use curl (i.e. does it have to be in a browser? If so, I'd hafta roll my own solution, I NEED non-browser support.).  If it doesn't, how do I roll my own?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My understanding is that you can use the tokens to log in or to hit arbitrary pages that need authentication, even with cURL. If you look in `config/initializers/devise.rb`, there should be a line that says something like:

```
config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token
```

Whatever the name of the `token_authentication_key` is should match what you put as the query or form parameter in your request. You used `authentication_token` in your example, not sure if you changed devise.rb to match that or not.

If you want to figure out how things are working internally, I would try `git clone git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git` and search for the methods you need clarification of.

Here are some sample cURL requests (I made a custom Users::SessionsController that extends Devise::SessionsController and overrides the create method to handle JSON.)

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
      end
      format.json do
        render :json => { :response => 'ok', :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token }.to_json, :status => :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then the cURL requests I gave:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json' -d 'user[email]=example@example.com&user[password]=password'
-> {"response":"ok","auth_token":"ABCDE0123456789"}

curl -L 'http://localhost:3000/profile?auth_token=ABCDE0123456789'
-> got page that I wanted that needs authentication
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped *nodnod* I wasn't aware that I was supposed to pass "auth token" (authentication_token is how it's stored in the db). I also thought it was supposed to be passed as a log in, not with every command. Works like a charm, now!

Comment: Anthony, could you advice what could be wrong if auth_token is not generated during user sign_up/sign_in? I'm using mongo_mapper. In the model I've got ensure_authentication_token! method, which resets token if it's blank.

Comment: Seems like a different question. Maybe you could open another question for it.

Comment: Off topic, I know, but Mike Bevz: Did you also put in an authentication token field in the database? I remember back when I was starting I had accidentally only added it to the model, and not the database migration.

Answer (score 5):

see this article: http://www.hyperionreactor.net/blog/token-based-authentication-rails-3-and-rails-2

Basically all you need is to append the token to your requests and you're automatically authenticated, i.e.
localhost:3000/posts.xml?auth_token=the_token

Comment: To read the article - http://web.archive.org/web/20101003082438/http://www.hyperionreactor.net/blog/token-based-authentication-rails-3-and-rails-2

Answer (score 3):

This was a good starting point for me:

Migration to add `authentication_token`:

```
class AddTokenBasedAuthentication < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :authentication_token, :string
    add_index :users, :authentication_token, unique: true
  end
end
```

And then in the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: <your login GET action>

  private 

  def authenticate_user_from_token!
    email = params[:email].presence
    user  = email && User.find_by(email: email)

    sign_in user if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, params[:auth_token])
  end
end
```

And then the link construction is just

```
www.yoursite.com/?email=the@email.address&auth_token=whatever_auth_token_is_stored_for_that_user
```

sources:
[this gist](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6#file-2_safe_token_authentication-rb) linked to from [devise's wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example), & [this tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20101003082438/http://www.hyperionreactor.net/blog/token-based-authentication-rails-3-and-rails-2) (mentioned above)