# devise authentication via ruby script

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, rest, devise

I have small application, and I will have some external applications put data to this service over http with rest. I already have it working but without authentication. In portal I use devise, and my question is: how to (example desired) authenticate to portal from ruby script level? What to add to following script to authenticate first? I want to protect this controller with devise and then I need authentication part to following script.

```
require "net/http"
require "json"

@host = "localhost"
@port = 3000
@post_ws = "/external/rd"

@req_body = {
"device" => {
  "name" => "device_json", 
  "operating_system_id" => "7", 
  "hash_string" => "jfsg3k4ovj0j02jv", 
  "user_id" => "1"
}
}.to_json

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@post_ws, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
req.body = @req_body
response = Net::HTTP.new(@host, @port).start {|http| http.request(req) }
```

Regards, 
Mateusz

Comment: I see token_authenticatable might help, but don't know so far, how to obtain token from script, so still no solution :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is solution:

I used token_authenticatable from devise.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627703/using-devise-tokens-to-log-in-is-this-built-in/4670812#4670812) is one great answer how to implement it with json. I had some trouble and described them [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912542/routingerror-uninitialized-constatnt). There is also answer.

Here goes example code:

```
require "net/http"
require "json"

@host = "localhost"
@port = 3000
@post_sign = "/users/sign_in.json"
@post_ws = "/external/rd"

@req_sign = {
"user" => {
  "email" => "some@email.com", 
  "password" => "123456" 
}
}.to_json

sig = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@post_sign, initheader = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
sig.body = @req_sign


http = Net::HTTP.new(@host, @port).start
resp1 = http.request(sig)
puts "Response: #{resp1.code} , Message: #{resp1.message} , Body: #{resp1.body}"

if resp1.code == "200" then 
  puts "logged in"
  json_resp = JSON.parse(resp1.body)
  @auth_token = json_resp['auth_token']

  @req_body = {
  "device" => {
    "name" => "device_json", 
    "operating_system_id" => "7", 
    "hash_string" => "jfsg3k4ovj0j02jv" 
  }, 
  "auth_token" => @auth_token 
  }.to_json
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@post_ws, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
  req.body = @req_body

  response = http.request(req)
  puts "Response: #{response.code} , Message: #{response.message} , Body: #{response.body}"
end
```

Regards, 
Mateusz