# RoutingError uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise

I want to use token_authenticatable in my application (using Devise).

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627703/using-devise-tokens-to-log-in-is-this-built-in/4670812#4670812) answer I added `class Users::SessionsController` in file `app/controllers/users_sessions_controller.rb` (is file location correct?).

To generate authentication_token in database I added line `current_user.reset_authentication_token!` as fourth line of create method.

Using "Configuring Controllers" section from [devise docimentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) I added line `devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "users/sessions"}` to my routes.

I also have file `app/views/users/session/new.html.erb`.

Now when I try to log in or log out in browser, I get `Routing Error uninitialized constant Users`.

I have no idea what happens. I think I named controller class wrong, or placed it incorrectly, but don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your controller named `Users::SessionsController` then it need to be in `app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb`

If you don't want nested folders for your controllers you could also do

```
class UserSessionsController
```

located at `app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb` with the routes being: `devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "user_sessions"}`

Comment: Yeah, exactly! I figured it out yesterday, but your answer is correct and helpful. Thanks for explanation :)

Comment: Two years later, you just made my night a bit less scary! :)