# Obtain access token on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, devise, httprequest, access-token

I use devise for authentication on Rails. Currently I'm testing some POST functions for the APIs and I want to do that with cRUL, so I need access token to get approved by devise. Then I can use cURL like

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H 
'Authorization: Token token=""' -X POST -d '{"name": "paul 
allen","first_name":"paul","last_name":"allen","middle_name":"","gender":"m",
"dob":"1/2/1980","dod":""}' http://localhost:3000/?auth_token=OyZSe8ozy_os5acibqNC
```

but how can I get the auth_token? (OyZSe8ozy_os5acibqNC)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627703/using-devise-tokens-to-log-in-is-this-built-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise token can be return in the controller:

```
  render :status=>200, :json=>{:token=>@user.authentication_token}
```