# Direct sign in link with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason we need to provide a direct sign on link to our user by email.

something like:
`www.website.com/user/sign_in/:hash`

And the user click on the link he would be automatically sign in.

But I have no idea where to start and it doesn't seem to be built in the gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use an auth token to sign the user in directly. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627703/using-devise-tokens-to-log-in-is-this-built-in) probably has all the details you need on getting this implemented properly.