# testing an API with postman & simulating logged in user in request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, postman

I am building an API in ruby on rails. The API has a authentification system created with Devise. I wanted to test my API methods using postman with http request but everytime I try I get the following response :

```
{
  "error": "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
}
```

How can I simulate a logged in user in my postman request to make my request work ? Or is there a better way to test my API ?

Comment: Is your API really using  cookie based authentication?

Comment: Need more information. What type of authentication is the API using? Is it token based?

Comment: I am not really sure, I know the auth system was created with devise & that in the schema the users table has an authentication_token column

Comment: May duplicate this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627703/using-devise-tokens-to-log-in-is-this-built-in

Answer (score 0):

You need a token based authentication to properly authenticate an `api` with devise. Token authentication is no longer included in `devise` gem but there is another gem called [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) that uses devise for authenticating apis using tokens.

It sends authentication headers in the response headers after a successful first sign in using email and password, you have to use these headers for every other request that you send to the application to be properly auhenticated.

Comment: In that case, is there a way to force Postman to refresh token header for next request each time after a new one has come in previous response?